# Modifying certain array indexes in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array of shape (5, x, y).

I want to modify every element in the first three channels only by an equation

`element = (element - a)/b`.

I want the other two channels to remain the same. How would you index the array to achieve this?

Comment: I think that you can find the answer to this from reading the basic indexing docs on numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since shape is `(channels, x, y)` you can use

```
x = np.random.rand(5,300,400)
a,b = 10,15
x[0:3] = (x[0:3] - a)/b
```

Comment: `x[0:3] -= a; x[0:3] /= b;` is more space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Generally one would use indices to get a slice of the array with only relevant values.

```
>>> desired_shape = (5, 2, 2) # xy = (2,2) in this example

>>> ary = np.array(range(5 * 2 * 2))
>>> ary.shape = desired_shape
>>> ary
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])

>>> channels_view = ary[:3, ...] # up to 3 in 1st axis, preserve the others
>>> channels_view
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])

>>> ary[:3, ...] = (ary[:3, ...] - a) / b
```

It is also possible to use np.view(), so we can string more operations without having to slice the array every time.

```
>>> view = ary.view()
>>> view = view[:3, ...]
>>> view
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
```

For this example, let's suppose we want to halve all the values in the first three channels for now:

```
>>> view //= 2 # use //= rather than /=, because this is an integer array, and we didn't specify a dtype, so numpy assumes fixed point integers (longs) rather than floats
>>> view
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 5]]])

>>> ary
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 1,  1]],

       [[ 2,  2],
        [ 3,  3]],

       [[ 4,  4],
        [ 5,  5]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])
```

But uh oh! Turns out we actually had to multiply this by several factors of a number!

```
>>> factors_of_420
[2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Kind of a dumb example, I know, but just assume we can't know what the number is ahead of time. Like, just pretend we're getting the factors from a TCP server or something.

We could write it like this:

```
>>> ary
```

array([[[ 0,  1],
[ 2,  3]],

```
   [[ 4,  5],
    [ 6,  7]],

   [[ 8,  9],
    [10, 11]],

   [[12, 13],
    [14, 15]],

   [[16, 17],
    [18, 19]]])

>>> for fac in factors_of_420:
...     ary[:3, ...] = ary[:3, ...] * fac
... 
>>> ary
array([[[   0,  420],
        [ 840, 1260]],

       [[1680, 2100],
        [2520, 2940]],

       [[3360, 3780],
        [4200, 4620]],

       [[  12,   13],
        [  14,   15]],

       [[  16,   17],
        [  18,   19]]])
```

But that's a bit ugly, isn't it? Also, I bet running the slicing operation twice (once for setting, and once for getting) for every factor in the list can be a bit of a performance hit.

This is where view shines. We can just make one view, and operate on that, and numpy applies the operations to the underlying array for us:

We don't need to sacrifice anything. We make nicer *and* faster code at the same time!

```
>>> ary
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])

>>> view = ary.view()[:3, ...] # make our pre-sliced view, yum!
>>> view
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])

>>> for fac in factors_of_420:
...     view *= fac # use the *= (in place) operator, because 'view =' sets view to something else and does not apply to ary
...
>>> view
array([[[   0,  420],
        [ 840, 1260]],

       [[1680, 2100],
        [2520, 2940]],

       [[3360, 3780],
        [4200, 4620]]])
>>> ary
array([[[   0,  420],
        [ 840, 1260]],

       [[1680, 2100],
        [2520, 2940]],

       [[3360, 3780],
        [4200, 4620]],

       [[  12,   13],
        [  14,   15]],

       [[  16,   17],
        [  18,   19]]])
```

Let's see what timing tells us.

```
>>> class WeirdSliceMultiplier:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.factors = [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
...     def setup(self):
...         self.ary = np.reshape(range(5 * 2 * 2), (5, 2, 2))
...     def setup_with_view(self):
...         self.setup()
...         self.view = self.ary.view()[:3, ...]
...     def multiply_every_slice(self):
...         for fac in self.factors:
...             self.ary[:3, ...] = self.ary[:3, ...] * fac
...     def multiply_view(self):
...         for fac in self.factors:
...             self.view *= fac

>>> timeit.timeit(multiplier.multiply_every_slice, multiplier.setup, number=50000) # 'slice for every factor' version
0.9404756519943476

>>> timeit.timeit(multiplier.multiply_view, multiplier.setup_with_view, number=50000) # 'slice view ahead of time' version
0.8748960520024411
```

Note in the second timeit call that `view` is set in the setup (preciesly, in `setup_with_view`), rather than the actual function being timed. This is because setting view doesn't count to the final time, as it is supposed to be ahead of time, and we're only counting the actual operation of multiplication, not any others that apply to view but may be stringed before or after.

**Edit:** Also, as @MadPhysicist pointed out in @mujiga's answer, we may actually prefer using the inplace operators. In fact, we already use them in the `multiply_view` function, so using inplace operators for both is a fairer comparison:

```
>>> class WeirdSliceMultiplier:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.factors = [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
...     def setup(self):
...         self.ary = np.reshape(range(5 * 2 * 2), (5, 2, 2))
...     def setup_with_view(self):
...         self.setup()
...         self.view = self.ary.view()[:3, ...]
...     def multiply_every_slice_inplace(self):
...         for fac in self.factors:
...             self.ary[:3, ...] *= fac
...     def multiply_view(self):
...         for fac in self.factors:
...             self.view *= fac
...
>>> multiplier = WeirdSliceMultiplier()

>>> timeit.timeit(multiplier.multiply_every_slice_inplace, multiplier.setup, number=50000) # 'slice for every factor' version, but with inplace operators
1.0672136489883997
>>> timeit.timeit(multiplier.multiply_view, multiplier.setup_with_view, number=50000) # 'slice view ahead of time' version again for comparison
0.9300520950055216
```

The strange change in the time to execute `setup_with_view`, possibly to do with the CPU load average or something, can be fixed using a normalizing factor:

```
>>> old_viewslice_time = 0.8748960520024411
>>> new_viewslice_time = 0.9300520950055216
>>> norm_fac = old_viewslice_time / new_viewslice_time
>>> norm_fac
0.9406957488733435
>>> new_viewslice_time * norm_fac # should be very similar to old_viewslice_time
0.8748960520024411

>>> new_everyslice_inplace_time = 1.0672136489883997
>>> new_everyslice_inplace_time * norm_fac
1.003923342742996
```